# How to write inline code documentation in Liquid template files

Tags: liquid, liquid-template

Writing Liquid code can become complex. I like to know what people do for documentation inline. Something like JSDoc for example? Love to hear!

Myself use things like this:

```
{#-
  This is a Liquid code block that does something important.

  Parameters:
  - param_1: String
  - param_2: Object with property.
-#}
{% include 'path/to/file',
  param_1: 'my value',
  param_2: object.property %}
```